# AWS Python SDK - Sending CLI Commands

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-cli

I know the AWS Python SDK (Boto/Boto3) has resources for the various AWS services (https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/resources.html) but I'm wondering if there's a resource to send a straight AWS CLI command e.g., so I can create an AWS EMR Cluster like `aws emr create-cluster ...configuration stuff here...`. Is there anything like `cli = boto.resource('cli')` or would I just use regular Python to execute a bash command e.g.,

```
from subprocess import call
call(["aws emr create-cluster ...configuration stuff here..."])
```

Comment: It would be a little unusual to use Python to invoke the awscli, when you have the boto3 Python library package available to you.

Comment: I know it doesn't exactly answer your question, but out of curiosity I was wondering why not use infrastructure as code like Terraform for example? It seems like writing automation in python to create infrastructure is to reinvent the wheel in this case. Either way you will also need to orchestrate your environment with the cli configured and installed, seems like an overhead

Comment: @Dvir669 I see myself in a similar situation like OP. Basically there is a level below full blown Terraform and the like. You have two or there CloudFormation Templates, and all you want is to issue a small number of ever-the-same aws CLI commands. Kind of wrap up and document your everyday routine, which you do mostly for yourself. Any kind of engineering an infrastructure would be overkill in such a case

Comment: @Ichthyo I hear you, but even then I won't use the CLI, I'll go with one of the SDK released. It is a lot simpler as you said to write a script with any SDK client, I'm using Ruby for example to redeploy instances without our tagging convention - all I'm saying that if you're already investing the time to configure the environment to work with the CLI and to write a script on top of it, I think it's the same effort to use TF.

Answer (score 4):

Boto3 has two levels of APIs. There's the **Client (low-level) API** which provides a mapping to the AWS CLI, then there's the **Resource (high level) API** which provides resource objects and collections which you can treat like any other object (iterate through, access certain methods and parameters, etc).

In your case, `boto.resource('cli')` doesn't really make sense, since the CLI isn't a resource. You're looking for a **client** level API if you want to provision EMR resources (I know that's a little bit confusing).

Boto3 has an EMR client (`client = boto3.client('emr')`) which you can use to create EMR resources as you would with the CLI. [You can see the documentation for this here.](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/emr.html)

Comment: One reason I was thinking of using the CLI to create an EMR is because I can create the EMR using the AWS Management Console (which is much easier to use) then test the EMR and when I'm happy with it I can simply export the CLI creation command by pressing the button on the UI screen then just use that command in a CLI command. But I know this isn't ideal because then I have to figure out when the EMR is booted up and add a worker group and stuff.

Comment: Another reason I may want to use the CLI to create my EMR is because as with Data Pipeline they don't offer the Security-Configuration field as shown in my question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50399662/3299397

Comment: Maybe write a helper that takes the aws CLI generated from the Management Console and converts it to a boto3.client command? This wouldn't be too hard. You could just have the aws CLI command as a string in your code. As for your question about Security-Configuration, I'm afraid I can't answer that since I'm not familiar with with those specifics.

Comment: Yeah so that's what I was thinking you can just copy the CLI command from the management console and execute it using the string that has the command in it. I was just wondering if there was a boto3 class that I can use to execute the command or if I just execute it like any regular shell command using the standard Python library.

Comment: If there's absolutely no other way to do it, `subprocess` module is your best bet. Just remember when you use `subprocess.call()` you give the arguments as a list, rather than a single string. So it would be, `subprocess.call(['aws', 'cli', ... ,])`

Comment: Thanks, actually after looking at this http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.create_security_configuration more closely it looks like Boto3 has a lot more support for all the fields than Data Pipeline does so I think I'm good with using the Boto3 EMR Client to do everything.

Comment: Yea Boto3 is awesome. One of if not the best AWS SDKs available. I'm looking at you AWS SDK for Node.js >:(